# Table cell with absolute positioned child issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with the following scenario:

I have a table where one of the cells have an input field.

```
<td id="myCell"><input type="text" class="myInput"></td>
```

So I want a floating box showing some results for what is typed in the input field. That's all fine so far, the floating box show up with results in the right place, but when I click in one of the results, the box hides with no apparent reason. 
The results box is appended with:

```
$("#myCell").append("<div class='searchResults'><a href='#' class='searchItem'>text</a></div>")
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.searchResults{
     z-index: 1000;
     top:30px;
     left:0px; 
     padding: 0px;
     position:absolute;           
     background-color: white;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     min-width: 100px;
     text-align: left;
 }
```

Even with no event handler for .searchResults, it hides when clicked. And using this code to handle click events:

```
$(document).on("click", ".searchItem", function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Nothing happens.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: `So I want a floating box showing some results for what is typed in the input field. That's all fine so far, the floating box show up with results in the right place` Provide this relevant code in question, maybe an event bubbling issue.

Comment: **Never** try to use absolute positioning *inside* tables.

Comment: remove # from href or remove href then it works because This is just a ''null'' value - which means the anchor will be seen as live (and would also enable use of the <title> tag), and should produce a hand pointer on hover - but it's use will take the user back to the same page he is on. Sometimes a better option for a ''live'' link but one which goes nowhere is -

<a href="javascript: void(0)">I am a useless link</a>

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. The main problem is that I need a box that pops below the table cell so it acts as a select. Someone has done something like this? I have good jquery knowledge, but nothing seems to work properly...

Comment: @connexo, is there a reason for this?  thanks for you reply!